# JVMs terminate simultaneously with error code 143

Tags: java, linux, signals, heap-memory

I am running an web application in Linux and observing no memory spike. No logs are captured in var/log/messages.
Can anyone tell me what are the possible scenarios when JVMs are terminated abruptly.
Is there any specific reason?

Comment: `/var/log/messages` does not generally contain web server logs. What do the logs of your application server say?

Comment: @thkala no logs are captured in /var/log/messages

Comment: @David this is not a duplicate. I have gone through the post which you have mentioned.

Comment: @Shriram: `/var/log/message` is *not* the application server log file. Where *that* is depends on your configuration...

Comment: Can you say more? Are you using tomcat or jetty or jboss? Does it happen with the base installation or does it require having a particular web app loaded?

Comment: i am using tomcat6.0.41 with our app installed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your linux system in wantof resources such as memory? Itcould be thst an external process such as OOM killed it. Check the system logs. Can you replicate it or is it sporadic?

Comment: i've checked OOM in system logs. Nothing has been updated. Even i tried by setting -17 for my process.